# How to deal with an IO and CPU bound at the same time in the context of parallelism?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

Is it possible launch multiple threads on all available CPUs rather than one? An example code would be great.

Alternatively, can I span multiple processes and then create multi threading within each process?

I am using multithreading which works fine for IO side of my script. However, my script is also computation expensive so I would like to launch multiple threads on multiple CPUs.

My code flow:

```
def worker(url):
    extract url (io bound)  
    process url content (cpu bound)
```

What should be the efficient way to deal with such type of worker?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding python GIL - I/O bound vs CPU bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574367/understanding-python-gil-i-o-bound-vs-cpu-bound)

Comment: basically you cant, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1294402/1695172

Comment: You have to use multiprocessing for that due to the GIL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible launch multiple threads on all available CPUs rather than one?

In general, threads run on whatever CPU is available. Unless you have specified a thread/process to run on a specific CPU. (How this is done varies per operating system)

However, if you are using the Python implementation from python.org ("CPython"), it doesn't matter. CPython has a "Global Interpreter Lock" that *enforces* that only one thread at a time is executing Python bytecode. So using threads will not yield improved processing performance with CPython.

So for computationally expensive tasks, you should probably use the `multiprocessing` module to do it in different processes. If the same work is done on a lot of data, using a `multiprocessing.Pool` is generally a good idea.